# Bitfields misbehave in C# structure

Tags: c#, structure

min : 6 bits
res1 : 1 bit
iv : 1 bit

Everything in the struct looks great but i don't get the expected result !

```
    struct cp56time2a
{

    internal byte cp56time2a_data1; 


    public byte min
    {
        get { return (byte)(cp56time2a_data1 & 0x3f); }
        set { cp56time2a_data1 = (byte)((cp56time2a_data1 & ~0x3f) | (value & 0x3f)); }
    }                                           //min :6;   0..59 
    public byte res1
    {
        get        { return (byte)((cp56time2a_data1 >> 6) & 0x01); }
        set        { cp56time2a_data1 = (byte)((cp56time2a_data1 & ~(0x01 << 6)) | (value & 0x01) << 6); }
    }
    public byte iv
    {
        get        { return (byte)((cp56time2a_data1 >> 7) & 0x01); }
        set        { cp56time2a_data1 = (byte)((cp56time2a_data1 & ~(0x01 << 7)) | (value & 0x01) << 7); }
    }         
}
```

I have tried to assign this value to each of the structure fields : 0x55=0 1 010101

Simple Test code :

```
        T.min = 0x55 ;     
        Console.WriteLine("min = {0}", T.min);
        Console.WriteLine("res1 = {0}", T.res1);
        Console.WriteLine("iv = {0}", T.iv);
        Console.WriteLine("cp56time2a_data1 = {0}",T.cp56time2a_data1);

        T.res1 = 0x55 ;
        Console.WriteLine("min = {0}", T.min);
        Console.WriteLine("res1 = {0}", T.res1);
        Console.WriteLine("iv = {0}", T.iv);
        Console.WriteLine("cp56time2a_data1 = {0}", T.cp56time2a_data1);

        T.iv = 0x55 ;
        Console.WriteLine("min = {0}", T.min);
        Console.WriteLine("res1 = {0}", T.res1);
        Console.WriteLine("iv = {0}", T.iv);
        Console.WriteLine("cp56time2a_data1 = {0}", T.cp56time2a_data1);`
```

Which is expected to show : `min =21 || res1 = 1 || iv = 0`

but this is what i get : [image]

The internal byte of the structure is misbehaving . YOUR IDEAS PLEASE !!

Comment: what is the point of making `res1` and `iv` a `byte` instead of a `bool`? The can only ever represent `1` or `0`. Assigning `0x55` to them is misleading.

Comment: All the results are correct. Nothing is misbehaving. Can you explain why you think they are wrong?  Why do you expect it to show that res1 = 1 **before** you assign to res1? You never assign anything to it so it stays zero!  When you do assign something to it -- the low bit of 0x55 -- it changes to 1.

Comment: @Rotem i have Tons of bytes to read from buffers and i don't want to make masks and shifting inside functions . Besides , i have similar structs that are composed of several 1|2|3|4|5 bit(s) sequence : so i am not complicating things ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two properties `res1` and `iv`, you have this: `value & 0x01` In other words you are only taking the least significant bit of the value assigned to these properties.

Also when you read those properties you do this: `& 0x01`. So it's pretty obvious these properties were intended to read and write one bit, i.e. they are `0` or `1`.

Comment: you're right . thanks dude .

Comment: res1 : 'value & 0x40'  iv : 'value & 0x80' . that's  supposed to fix it .